# Share session cookie between Angular and local hybris

Tags: angular, session, cookies, session-cookies, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an Angular project running on http://localhost:4200, and a hybris server running on https://locahost:9002

Apparently the session cookie is not shared by default if the port and protocols are different.

Is there any additional configuration I can add to share a session cookie between the two servers?

Comment: using cookie for angular sessions is a bad idea, because javascript cookies can easily be altered, I'd suggest you to check JWT instead, using localstorage to store it. That being said, you can't share a session between these two.

Comment: The issue is that I dont have access to the backend, and it is already using session cookies. I am not even sure Hybris supports JWT?